# Closing GitHub feature branches while retaining labels in Network Graph

Tags: github

I love GitHub's "Network Graph" view.  I like how it can give me an overview of the progression of a repository over time:

[image]

Unfortunately, I've noticed one problem.  When I'm done merging branches into master, if I delete the original feature branch from `remote` (GitHub), the little branch name labels disappear.  This results in a graph that looks like this:

[image: Closed (and deleted) branches]

I know I can hover over the commits to see the commit message, but it's so much more helpful (to me, at least) to have the branch name labels to provide a general indication of what I'm looking at.

Is there a way to delete these branches from `remote` and have this graph retain its labels?  Or, is there a better approach that I'm overlooking?

Comment: The "little branch name labels" *are* the branches. Why would you expect the branches to remain on the network graph after you have removed them from the repository?

Comment: As @Chris has said, in Git, a "branch" means a pointer to a single commit, not a "set of commits in a single path" as they popularly believe it. Once you delete "the branch", you lose this label as well.

I have added an answer with a solution, but I don't think it's good practice. You should not want to determine what a branch was about by looking at it's label, you should be able to do that by looking at the message where it merges to another branch.

Comment: @Chris: I use `-no-ff` to provide a consistent structure of feature branches, regardless of whether they are in development or merged.  Having these GitHub branch labels persist in the "Network Graph" is related to this desire of maintaining a consistent, easily understood historical perspective on repository evolution.  I understand that from a Git perspective, what I'm trying to do may not make sense.  However, from a usability perspective, it certainly does.  This is part of why I specifically posted this question about #GitHub and not #Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to keep the name of a deleted branch and remember it's last pointed commit in Git.

In some Git GUIs, they show tag names like this, so you could add a tag to the last commit of a given branch. But GitHub doesn't show tags like that.

So, in GitHub the only way to achieve what you seek is not deleting branches.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question as well as providing background on why it's not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I rename my merged branches "zCLOSED-oldname" so that they still have references, but sort to the bottom of the Branch pulldown list.

Unfortunately, you can't rename directly in GitHub, so you have to rename locally, push the "new" branch, and then delete the original Branch name from GitHub.